# MYSQL запрос: добавление данных в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом. В MYSQL есть 2 таблицы : messages

[image: Imgur]

и dialogs

[image: Imgur]

Скрипт ниже должен добавлять в данные таблицы данные об отправителе по id и получателе, а также сообщение и еще пару параметров, но проблемы с добавлением в таблицу messages.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND `to_id` = '".$_GET['mes']."' LIMIT 5",$mysql_connect) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count=0) {
    ###
    mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `messages` (`from_id`,`to_id`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."','".$_GET['mes']."') ",$mysql_connect) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND `to_id` = '".$_GET['mes']."' LIMIT 1",$mysql_connect) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
$dialog_id=$data['dialog_id'];
}
    mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `dialogs` (`dialog_id`,`messages`,`date`) VALUES ('".$dialog_id."','".$_POST['messages']."','30.09.1923') ",$mysql_connect) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}
else{  
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `from_id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND `to_id` = '".$_GET['mes']."' LIMIT 1",$mysql_connect) or die(mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
$dialog_id=$data['dialog_id'];
}
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `dialogs` (`dialog_id`,`messages`,`date`) VALUES ('".$dialog_id."','".$_POST['messages']."','30.09.1923') ",$mysql_connect) or die("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
}


    }




?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Документ без названия</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<textarea name="messages" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Отправить" />
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Куча устаревших mysql_query - не хорошо. Ибо устарел. Юзайте PDO с его интересной фишкой, как предподготовленные запросы - prepare.
2. Все можно отправить одним запросом, гуглите UNION.

Код сократится раза в 4.

Comment: На данном этапе это для меня сложно, понял, что ошибка в том, что у меня присутствуют $_GET и $_POST запросы, но как это устранить, не знаю. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно ли использование get  и post запроса в одном обработчике?

Comment: @golomazov только в теории. Точнее, можно получать одновременно GET и POST параметры в PHP, но по факту это просто огромная красная лампочка с сиреной, которая верещит о том, что всё плохо.

Comment: @golomazov 
никто Ва не запрещает использовать одновременно GET и POST запросы в скрипте. Но, дабы не было конфликтов, стоит для GET и POST запросов использовать разные функции. Но всё же это тоже не очень хорошо.

Я повторюсь, Ваш код можно сократить в 3-4 раза, используя тот же UNION, поверьте, там ничего сложного нет. Ведь с синтаксисом SQL Вы уже знакомы, значит и тут разберетесь. 

И всё же определитесь с методом передачи данных и приведите всё к одному. Меньше заморочек выйдет.

Comment: Все разобрался, проблему решил. Всем спасибо.